# Lumen PHP change field name in JSON

Tags: php, json, lumen

I have a table in my database with some fields:

- id
- name
- xx

When I call an API, I get one item from my database and return it:

```
$table = MyTable::select('table.*')->where('id', $id)->first();
return response()->json($table, 200);
```

I get a json like that:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "user1",
  "xx": 0
}
```

I can remove the `xx` field by adding it to he `$hidden` field inside the model.

How can I rename the `xx` in `yy` ?
Does it exists a simpler way than adding a getter/setter on a yy field inside my model ?

To get:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "user1",
  "yy": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method is using `setHidden` and `select alias` like below :

```php
$table = MyTable::select('table.*', "table.xx as yy")->where('id', $id)->first()->setHidden(["xx"]);
return response()->json($table, 200);
```

Or you can map response using Associative Array but you have to map every fields like below :

```php
$table = MyTable::select('table.*')->where('id', $id)->first();
return response()->json([
  "id" => $table->id,
  "name" => $table->name,
  "yy" => $table->xx
], 200);
```

Or unset like below :

```php
$table = MyTable::select('table.*')->where('id', $id)->first()->toArray();
$table["xx"] = $table["yy"];
unset($table["yy"]);
return response()->json($table, 200);
```